# Make Tab Layout Indicator smaller than the tab title

Tags: android, xml, indicator

Make small indicator for tab layout tabs. I have tried with tabIndicatorFullWidth but it only wraps up with the title of tab, I want to make it more smaller.

Example Image:
[image: example]

Comment: Please add your own code which you have done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom indicator drawable for small indicator tabs.

like this>>

tab_layout_indicator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="5dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/green"></solid>
             
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And Use this indicator to your xml layout file.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_layout_indicator"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabMode="scrollable"        
                      ></com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Comment: When you say it isnt working, please make yourself more clear. What doesn't work? What's the result you got from these codes?

Comment: No indicator found in tab after updating my code to this one.